# Does unit testing on Services make sense?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, layer

I am writing an app in Java Spring which consists of layers. The responsibilities of them are:

- REST/Controller layer - handle incoming requests, user authentification, parsing request bodies and communicating with Service layer according to the request
- Service layer - mostly deal with creating/editing/deleting associations between and states of Entities. Communicates with DAO layer and "Utility"
- DAO layer - persistence, will save/delete/find requested entities
- Entity/Object? layer - object representing the domain of the app, rather dumb functionality, mainly for keeping track of associations
- "Utility" layer - not really a layer, provides services like checking for permissions between objects (Object A wants to add object B to object C, for that it needs permission XYZ...) etc

I have been writing some tests while developing and now that I have thought about it, they have been kind of integration tests. The general flow of the tests can be described as:

1. Call serviceX to create object A
2. Call serviceX to create object B
3. Call serviceY to do something with objects A and B
4. Call serviceX to report state of objects A and B and check if everything is correct

In each step the services called the DAO layer and saved/created/fetched objects which were then manipulated and the test checked if the manipulation was successful and as expected.

I am thinking about how exactly should a proper unit test look. I understand that I should mock every component the tested service depends on so that I can 'isolate' the behavior I want to test. However, most of the methods of services do not actually "return" anything, they only manipulate the entities.

The question I have is then - does it **always** make sense to Unit test layers/services of an app, or is it acceptable to test them as a whole?

---

**Appendix**

Example of one of the methods. This one is responsible for adding a new user to a group. Adding the member has to be done by a manager of the group. So the logic goes:

- Get parameters - manager, group, newUser
- If any of parameters are null, throw exception
- Call `permissionHandler` service and check if the `manager` user has enough permissions in `group` to complete this action
- Check if `newUser` already exists in the group. If yes, throw exception.
- If everything ok, call `groupMemberHelper` service to create a new `GroupMember` object representing the association between `user` and `group` (and some more info about the association)
- Add this `GroupMember` object to the group
- For all "items" the group already owns, call a helper service that creates a link between those items and the newly added user.

To test this method I would keep track of the `group`, `newUser` and all objects that this method affects and check if the state "before" and "after" are what I expect them to be.

I can't think of another way to test it without relying on the functions of the called services. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that I should mock every component the tested service depends on so that I can 'isolate' the behavior I want to test.

This widely held view is wrong. You do not *always* have to mock *every* collaborator.

When testing my presentation layer, I use a mock data layer and the real (non mock) service layer.

The fault with the widely held view is that there is a difference between specified behaviour and implementation details. Your tests should test the specified behaviour. They should not assume any particular implementation details. In most cases, the manner in which a high level layer interacts with a lower layer is not specified, other than that it's calls meet whatever preconditions the lower layer imposes. Therefore if you were to test a higher layer using a mocked lower layer, the mock has to provide the correct behaviour for *every one* of its methods, because you do not know which methods the higher layer will call. This can make a proper mock object just as complicated as the real object. In which case, using a mock gains you nothing.

A mock data layer is not too onerous because you can implement it as an in-memory store, using Maps and Lists, rather than a database, and use the same mock class for all your service layer and presentation layer tests.

Comment: Let me check if I understand you correctly. Would you say the general idea is that when testing a layer, it is "okay" to use the real implementations of layers underneath it? (except for data layer, which I agree is rather easy to mock)

Comment: @Martin Yes, it is OK. You must be judicious in which collaborators to mock, rather than blindly thinking you must mock everything. Or mock nothing.

Comment: I like the presentation/article from Martin Fowler where he shows on how to approach testing - http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/ . It was supposed to be a microservice testing guide, but I find actually really good for most software.

Answer (score 2):

The method from the example showed you that you're doing a lot in the service. That's what tests do by side effect - they show weak code architecture. Try moving validation logic to another bean, creation logic to a factory and so on. You'll have code which is easy to read, understand, maintain and unit test.

Comment: I was thinking about creating factory services, but then I didn't particularly liked the idea of having services with only one method, so I incorporated that functionality as part of the service layer. Though I guess it would make sense to have a factory and the flow: call a service to create an object. That delegates the creation to a factory, which returns a new object, that then gets persisted by the service calling an appropriate data layer method. Thanks